# is any sync-ml API available for server and client ??

Tags: c#, android, c, syncml

i want to make sync-ml server in .net .Is any API is available for it so that we can make sync-ml server in any languages ? I don't want to use funambol like software , it bound us to use it's API . Is any sync-ml API is available for client & server (client can be android or c platform device).

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at `SyncML Client API .NET` at [Syncmldotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/syncmldotnet/)